# Concatenation of pressed WM_Char key values win32API

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to capture the values of WM_CHAR keys, and then putting all the captured the values into a single string. I have tried to concatenate the pressed key value 2, 3, 4 and 5 with _tcscat, the resulting TCHAR string looks like this  "22232323423423452345"  I would like to know how to make TCHAR string looks like 2345.  The following is the code that I have.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

      static PMSG   pmsg ;  
      int           i, iType ;
      int           StrLen;
      TCHAR     StrBuf[9];
      static TCHAR         tBuf[32];
      TCHAR     MyTchar[8] = TEXT ("A");
      WORD          wCharCode;

     switch (message)
    {
      case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        SelectObject (hdc, GetStockObject (SYSTEM_FONT)) ;
        SetBkMode (hdc, TRANSPARENT) ;          
        for (i = min (cLines, cLinesMax), cScreenLine=1; i>0 ; i--, cScreenLine++)
        {
             iType  =   pmsg[i-1].message == WM_CHAR ;


     if (!iType)
            {

              StrLen= wsprintf(StrBuf, TEXT("%s"), TEXT(" "));
     }
            else
     {
    wCharCode = (WORD)(pmsg[i-1].wParam & 0xffff);
          memcpy(&MyTchar, &wCharCode, 2);
                 StrLen = wsprintf(StrBuf[2], TEXT("%s"), &MyTchar);
    _tcscat(tBuf, MyTchar);


      }


      EndPaint (hwnd, &ps) ;

      return 0 ;

     case WM_DESTROY:
         PostQuitMessage (0) ;
         return 0 ;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the message processing you have during the WM_PAINT message. You probably want to handle WM_CHAR as a separate message altogether where you can keep track of a string.

Outside of your `WndProc`, you will need `#include <string>;` and `std::wstring keyPresses;`

WM_CHAR can then be handled like any other event inside the WndProc.

```
case WM_CHAR:
    switch (wParam) 
    { 
        // First, handle non-displayable characters by beeping.
        case 0x08:  // backspace.
        case 0x09:  // tab.
        case 0x0A:  // linefeed.
        case 0x0D:  // carriage return.
        case 0x1B:  // escape.
        case 0x20:  // space.
            MessageBeep((UINT) -1); 
        break;

        // Next, handle displayable characters by appending them to our string.
        default:
            keyPresses += (wchar_t) wParam;
    } 
    break;
```

Then, you can do whatever manipulations you would like on this string, including [displaying it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) during the WM_PAINT message.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It seems that I can not put anything under WM_CHAR, my wm_paint would not paint any messages with any statment under wm_char.  Also, the resulting string of key pressed is 22334455 not 2345.  I appreciated for any suggestion that you would have!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++, use std::string or std::wstring. It will be much simpler and safer (no buffer overflows)

Answer (score 0):

Before you use string buffer, you should clear them first.
You can use
1. ZeroMemery
2. memset

And or

```
TCHAR     StrBuf[9];
====>
TCHAR     StrBuf[9] = {0};
```

finally, why u use tBuf as a static var?

Comment: tBuf was static is because I need stop concenation and passed the string to a function when the return key is pressed.